# Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 3 buttons in a row which all vary in width. I want them to all gain width the same to fill the remaining width of the row, so the widest will still be wider than the others etc.

You can see below that what I've tried to do with flex has resulted in all the buttons being the same width. I know `flex-grow` can be used to proportionally grow each item, but I can't work out how to get them all to grow in relation to their original size.

You can see in the second row that the blue item is larger than the other two. I just want all three to expand from their current size equally to fill the row.

Thanks

```css
.row-flex {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.button {
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.button--1 {
  background: red
}

.button--2 {
  background: green;
}

.button--3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-flex">
  <a href="#" class="button button--1">Single</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--2">Larger title</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--3">Another really large title</a>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="row">
  <a href="#" class="button button--1">Single</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--2">Larger title</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--3">Another really large title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

### Short Answer

Switch from `flex: 1` to `flex: auto`.

---

### Explanation

The `flex-grow` property factors in two key pieces of data:

1. The free space in the row / column where it is being used.
2. The value of the `flex-basis` property.

---

***Distribution of Free Space***

The `flex-grow` property distributes free space in the container among flex items in the same line.

If there is no free space, `flex-grow` has no effect.

If there is *negative free space* (i.e., the total length of flex items is greater than the length of the container), then `flex-grow` has no effect and `flex-shrink` comes into play.

---

***The `flex-basis` factor***

When `flex-basis` is `0`, `flex-grow` ignores the size of the content in flex items and treats all space on the line as free space.

This is *absolute* sizing. All space on the line is distributed.

When `flex-basis` is `auto`, the size of the content in flex items is  first deducted to determine the free space in each item. `flex-grow` then distributes the free space among items (based on each item's `flex-grow` value).

This is *relative* sizing. Only extra space on the line is distributed.

Here's an illustration from the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property):

[image]

---

***Examples:***

- `flex: 1` (absolute sizing)

This shorthand rule breaks down to: `flex-grow: 1` / `flex-shrink: 1` / `flex-basis: 0`

Applied to all flex items, this will make them equal length, regardless of content. (Note that in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54681689/3597276) an override of [default minimum sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276) will be necessary for this effect to occur.)

- `flex-grow: 1` (relative sizing)

This rule by itself will factor in both content size and available space, because [the default value for `flex-basis` is `auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property).

- `flex: auto` (relative sizing)

This shorthand factors in both content size and available space because it breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto`

More variations here: [**7.1.1. Basic Values of `flex`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

<sup>*additional keywords for search: difference between flex-basis auto 0 flex 1 auto*</sup>

Comment: This is a great answer, explaining the behaviour of `flex-basis` and how it solves the problem here really nicely - thanks!

Comment: in the second picture (for flex-basis 'auto' case), what do those 1 1, 1 1, 2 2 denotes? I understand that they are flex-grow factors, but what are they representing?

Comment: They represent the free space assigned to the `flex-grow` values (around the content). Each one of those numbers is a value of `flex-grow`. Because `flex-basis` is `auto`, the content length is factored in. @LokeshSanapalli

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is entirely what you are after, but if you just set `flex-grow:1` instead of `flex:1;`, I think that is your required result:

```css
.row-flex {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.button--1 {
  background: red
}

.button--2 {
  background: green;
}

.button--3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-flex">
  <a href="#" class="button button--1">Single</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--2">Larger title</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--3">Another really large title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property you can set proportions:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.button--1 {
  background: red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.button--2 {
  background: green;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}

.button--3 {
  background: blue;
  flex: 3 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<br/>

<div class="row">
  <a href="#" class="button button--1">Single</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--2">Larger title</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--3">Another really large title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic answer with (hopefully useful, explanatory) alternatives:

HTML:

```
<div class="row-flex">
  <a href="#" class="button button--1">Single</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--2">Larger title</a>
  <a href="#" class="button button--3">Another really large title</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  flex-grow: 1; /* make the item grow proportionally to its original size */
                /* default value is 0, the item does not grow */
                /* a meaningful default for flexbox items positioning with */
                /* justify-content: <value>; */      
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.button--1 {
  background: red
}

.button--2 {
  background: green;
}

.button--3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

The following CSS declarations also work because all they do is override the default `flex-grow: 0;` to the (for the desired behavior required) `flex-grow: 1;`:

```
.button {
  flex: auto;
  ...
}
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
.button {
  flex: 1 1 auto;    
  ...
}
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
.button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  ...
}
```