# How to create a flex item that shrinks before it wraps?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As can be seen in this [JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmf58kgp/), I basically try to use this CSS to create two divs that should fullfill these requirements:

- If twice the space of the wider item is available, both should use 50% width (that works)
- If not enough space for both items is available, they should wrap (that works)
- If enough space is available for both items, but less than twice the width of the wider one, the narrower item should shrink (that does NOT work, it wraps)

I don't understand this behavior, because I have set `flex-shrink` for the flex items, so they should be able to shrink - but they don't: If the narrower item would be less than 50% wide, it wraps.

```css
.m {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.l_1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.r_1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class=m>

  <div class=l_1>
    left_______________________________________________X
  </div>

  <div class=r_1>
    right
  </div>


</div>
```

(Tested on Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not `flex-shrink`. The problem is `flex-basis`. You have it set to 50%.

This means that `flex-grow` will add free space to the `flex-basis`, and each item will wrap quickly, before it has an opportunity to shrink.

Switch from `flex-basis: 50%` to `flex-basis: 0`.

More specifically, instead of `flex: 1 1 50%` use `flex: 1`, which breaks down to this:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

Now `flex-grow` distributes free space equally – not proportionally – to both items, and they can shrink before they wrap.

(Here's a more in-depth explanation: *[Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)*)

```css
.m {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.l_1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.r_1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=m>
  <div class=l_1>left_______________________________________________X</div>
  <div class=r_1>right</div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pmf58kgp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

When wrapping is enabled, it takes the place of shrinking, so where there is a condition that would trigger shrinking, it wraps instead - until there is only one item in the row, and if that's still bigger than the container, then it will shrink.

So, you need to set `flex-basis` for all boxes to the *minimum* size that block should be before wrapping.  Note: a box will never shrink further than its `minimum content width`, meaning you can set `flex-basis` to `0` and it will go by the minimum content width of each box.

Then, if you want the boxes to expand to fill the available space, then use the `flex-grow` property (first value in `flex`) to control the relative amount by which each one should grow.

Answer (score 0):

Flex-shrink will not apply with `flex-wrap: wrap` also applied. It will line wrap instead.

The only exception to this is when you only have one flex item in the row. Then it should allow for flex-shrink to apply.

Perhaps the appropriate fix is to only apply the `flex-wrap` within a media query, so it only happens in smaller viewports?