# Make flex items have equal width in a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want the headers (`h4.child-title`) to have the same length within the parent container in the below example.

But I'm not successful in achieving this.

```css
.top-level {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.section-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.child-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.vertical-separator {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level">
  <section class="section">
    <div claas="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div claas="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div claas="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the same width and height as section-child ?

Comment: I need the containers of "Title", "Longer title", "Much much longer title" to all have the same width

Comment: i.e all `div.section-child`s within parent `section.section` to have same width

Comment: In this example, the width of each `div.section-child` should equal to the width of `div.section-child` that has the content `Much much longer title`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Flexbox method

In order to make the text items (`.section-child`) equal width, you need to use `flex: 1 1 0`, which you have done. This is the same as saying `flex: 1`.

However, this by itself doesn't achieve the goal for two reasons:

1. The parent of `.section-child`, a flex container, but also a flex item in a larger container, is limited to the width of its content, by default. So it won't expand and the text can overflow the container. You need to apply `flex: 1` to `.section`, as well.
2. A flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content, by default. The initial setting is `min-width: auto`. So `flex: 1` cannot work to equally distribute container space, because a flex item cannot shrink past the longest item. You need to override this behavior with `min-width: 0`.

```css
.top-level {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.section-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.child-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.vertical-separator {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Now all flex items are equal width. However, because you have the text set to `nowrap`, it can overflow its boundaries. If you remove `nowrap`, everything  fits nicely.

```css
.top-level {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.section-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.child-title {
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}

.vertical-separator {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

More information:

- [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)
- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

---

### CSS Grid method

If your actual goal is to make all flex items in the row equal to the width of the longest item, that's something flexbox cannot do.

Flex can do equal width and equal height flex items, because it provides `flex: 1` on the main axis.

Flex can also do equal width and equal height columns / rows, because it provides `align-items: stretch` on the cross axis.

But there is nothing in the flexbox spec about equal size flex items based on the size of a particular sibling. However, flexbox's sister technology, CSS Grid, can do it.

By using Grid's `fr` unit, the width of columns in a grid can be set to the width of the longest column.

```css
.top-level {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1px 1fr 1px 1fr;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.section-child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 0;
  background-color: green;  
}

.child-title {
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}

.vertical-separator {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title text text text text text text text text text text</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title text text text text text text</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-separator"></div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Here's how it works:

- [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276)

Answer (score 8):

Flexbox is not the perfect choice for table like layout, but you can get close though:

- add `flex: 1 1 100%` to `sectionchild`, and it will shrink (or grow) equally, based on being set to be 100%
- add `overflow: hidden`, or `min-width`, to tell the `section-child` they are allowed to be smaller than their content
- add `flex-basis: 100%`, or `flex-grow: 1`, to `section` and it will take full with of its parent, the `top-level`

*As `vertical-separator`, I instead used a pseudo `::after` on every `section-child` but the first, and since it use absolute position, `position: relative` is needed on the `section-child`.*

```css
.top-level {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.section {
  flex-basis: 100%;              /*  added  */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.section-child {
  position: relative;             /*  added  */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 100%;                 /*  added  */
  overflow: hidden;               /*  added  */
}

.child-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.section-child + .section-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Several times in your code, you wrote `claas` instead of `class`:

```
<div claas="section-child">
  <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
  <!--A lot more content here-->
</div>
```

Then you should simplify your html structure by removing the `vertical-separator` divs and using css borders instead:

```css
.top-level {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.section-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.section-child:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-right: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.child-title {
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section-child">
      <h4 class="child-title">Much much longer title</h4>
      <!--A lot more content here-->
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I removed the `white-space: nowrap` for `.child-title` because flex values are just hints and without wrapping "Much much longer title" will take too much space. If you really want to use `nowrap`, you will have to ensure your container is large enough and maybe use overflow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo. I get that I can replace the child with borders.

But I dont want the nowrap to removed. Otherwise the section headers will be on multiple lines. The same goes for overflow.