# Setting a max-width for flex items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a filter section on my site, the content is all generated dynamically (so I can't add extra parents to it), and our styleguide creates them using flex items. I'd like to keep this functionality for the most part.

I want my 3 flex items to have a `max-width` and be floated left, leaving my non flex item floated right, in the overall container that is set to a max width of `1080px` sort of like this:

```
Option 1    Option 2    Option 3                                    Non-flex Item
```

I've tried setting the flex-align values and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778298/make-flex-items-have-equal-width-in-a-row), but that doesn't seem to work for this.

As of right now, this is the code that I am working with:

```html
<ul class="container">
   <li class="child">One</li>
   <li class="child">Three</li>
   <li class="child">Three</li>
   <div class="non-flex">
       I'm not a flex item
   </div>
</ul>
```

```css
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
        
.child {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}
```

I also made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfv323kq/1/) for you all to play around.

Comment: I think it would be better not to speak about "floating" elements unless you actually mean setting property `float` to some non-default value. It appears that this question was about alignment or justification instead.

Comment: also see Mozilla docs: [using auto margins for main axis alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#using_auto_margins_for_main_axis_alignment)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would apply a `width` or `min-width` to the `.child` items (or left/right padding that creates the distance between them) and `margin-left: auto` to the last item, which moves it right, independently from the others:

https://jsfiddle.net/6vwny6bz/2/

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.child {
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 80px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.non-flex {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="child">One</li>
  <li class="child">Three</li>
  <li class="child">Three</li>
  <div class="non-flex">
    I'm not a flex item
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Took a little tweaking but this works perfectly, thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! BTW: There is no need for all the flex settings in `.child`, so I erased them from the snippet above. They are flex *items* automatically (by defining their container as a flex container)

Comment: Yeah, those come from our global styleguide, so I can't really remove them, but appreciate the insight. I've never really worked with flex-items until we started this project so they're kind of confusing!

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to set margin-right: auto:

```
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: easiest solution , atleast for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
.non-flex{
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

to create more space in between the first 3 elements and the non-flex one

Comment: This is a bad solution considering there can be change on the items later on. Placing items with margin always leads to disorders.