# Bulma Inconsistent Input Width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bulma

[image]I have a simple form that is using the Bulma framework. I am getting inconsistent input widths and can't find a remedy. https://jsfiddle.net/onzpum90/ It seems to happen when the labels are long. If I kept short labels the problem is gone. Why is the label affecting the input width? May be a flexbox issue that I am not familiar with. Anyone know of a solution?

```
<form action="">
<div class="field">
<div class="field-body">
  <div class="field">
    <p class="control is-expanded">
      <label class="label">A very long label for a form</label> 
      <input type="text" name="" value="" class="input ">
     </p>
  </div> 
  <div class="field is-grouped">
    <p class="control is-expanded">
      <label class="label">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="input ">
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="field is-horizontal">
<div class="field-body">
  <div class="field">
    <p class="control is-expanded">
      <label class="label">Short Label</label> 
      <input type="text" name="" value="" class="input ">
     </p>
  </div> 
  <div class="field is-grouped">
    <p class="control is-expanded">
      <label class="label">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="input ">
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The div containers for the form elements (`.field`) are flex items sized with `flex-grow: 1`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px), print
.field-body > .field:not(.is-narrow) {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Although you've defined `flex-grow`, you haven't defined `flex-basis`. As a result, `flex-basis` remains at its default setting: `auto`.

With `flex-basis: auto`, container space is distributed *proportionally* among items based on the length of their content.

Hence, items with longer labels will be longer in length.

You can fix the problem by simply setting `flex-basis` to `0`.

Remove the `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` rules applied to `.field` and use this instead:

```
flex: 1 1 0
```

which is the same as:

```
flex: 1
```

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/onzpum90/1/)

For a complete explanation of the difference between `flex-basis: auto` vs `flex-basis: 0`, see this post: *[Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, exactly what I was looking for. This fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why `flex-basis: 0` not in official Bulma? Some side effects?