# Flex items in a row rendering at different widths

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I created 3 boxes using css flexbox in html but Chrome is rendering the boxes with different sizes.

[image]

Drag the border of the browser to make the view smaller.

Thanks for your help!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/labanino/pen/rGaNLP

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.flex {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex>section {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex>section:nth-child(1) {
  background: brown;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.flex>section:nth-child(2) {
  background: pink;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.flex>section:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <section>Brown</section>
  <section>Pink</section>
  <section>Green</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `auto` in your flex property for your items. Use 100%, and this will adapt the width in the flex box, and adjusts to any number of elements you add (in case you want to add more than 3).

```
.flex > section {
  flex: 1 1 100%;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The reason they're all different sizes is because  when you use `auto`, it bases its width on the content of the box. That's why the middle one isn't as wide, because the word 'pink' takes up less space than 'green'.

Comment: Very nice @Spartacus. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the source of the problem:

```
.flex > section { flex: 1 1 auto }
```

This breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto`

With `flex-basis: auto` you are sizing the item based on the length of the content. Hence, wider content will create wider items.

If you want equal size for all items in the row, then use:

- `flex-basis: 0`, and
- `min-width: 0` / `overflow: hidden`

With `flex-basis: 0` you're allocating to each item an equal distribution of space in the container. More details here: *[Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)*

With `min-width: 0` or `overflow: hidden` you're allowing items to shrink past their content, so they can remain equal size on smaller screens. More details here: *[Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)*

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}
.flex>section {
  flex: 1;          /* new; same as flex: 1 1 0 */
  overflow: hidden; /* new */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
.flex>section:nth-child(1) {
  background: brown;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.flex>section:nth-child(2) {
  background: pink;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.flex>section:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <section>Brown</section>
  <section>Pink</section>
  <section>Green</section>
</div>
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/veEoBm)