# Inserting divs into flex regular columns: column width and overflow problems

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to put 3 columns inside a container. They are supposed to have the same width and evenly distributed. I use `flex` for that and it works fine.

In the end I need to insert a collection of "cards" in each column ... Because the number of cards can cause the columns to have a greater height than what can be displayed in the browser, the container (the parent of the columns) has `overflow` set to `scroll`. So when that happens you can still scroll down to look at the cards that are at the bottom of the column.

I have two problems that I'd like to fix:

1) As soon as I insert a card in the left column, that columns becomes larger than the other two. If I set the column to `flex` and set `flex-grow` to `0` on the card, it makes no difference. I am not sure why?

## EDIT:

I fixed #1 by setting `width: 33%;` on `.column`.

===========================================================================

2) The left column is not drawn passed the bottom boundary of the browser, even though it contains cards causing the container to potentially overflow. What I want to do is be sure that the column "contains" the cards. How could I achieve that (using flex or not)?

I created a fidle and illustrated this problem with the figure below.

[JSFIDDLE is here](https://jsfiddle.net/dk51g968/)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) As soon as I insert a card in the left column, that columns becomes
>   larger than the other two. If I set the column to flex and set
>   flex-grow to 0 on the card, it makes no difference. I am not sure why?

`flex-grow` does not define the width, it define how the *available space* should be distributed.

You could use `flex-basis: 33.333%`

> 2) The left column is not drawn passed the bottom boundary of the
>   browser, even though it contains cards causing the container to
>   potentially overflow. What I want to do is be sure that the column
>   "contains" the cards. How could I achieve that (using flex or not)?

Change the `height: 100%` on `container` to `min-height: 100%`

Stack snippet

```css
html, body
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 border: 2px solid black;
 overflow: scroll;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 100%;                  /*  changed  to 'min-height'  */
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 background: grey;
 margin: 5px;
}

.article
{
 margin: 5px;
 background: white;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">


 <div class="column">
  <div class="article">article1</div>
  <div class="article">article2</div>
  <div class="article">article3</div>
  <div class="article">article4</div>
  <div class="article">article5</div>
  <div class="article">article6</div>
  <div class="article">article7</div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="column">col 2</div>
 <div class="column">col 3</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to LGSon and Michael B. I would have never thought trying out `min-height`. Worked great. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To make the columns equal width, instead of `flex: 1 1 auto`, use `flex: 1 1 0` (which is the same as `flex: 1`).

With `flex-basis: auto` the width of each column is based on its content, so equal width columns aren't guaranteed.

With `flex-basis: 0`, the width of all columns is an equal distribution of space in the container.

Here's a more complete explanation of `flex-basis` and the difference between `auto` and `0`.

- [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)

To make the divs respect their `height: 100px`, add `flex-shrink: 0`. Flex items have `flex-shrink: 1`, by default.

Here's a more complete explanation:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

To get the container to follow along, see [the other answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46456584/3597276).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: grey;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1;   /* adjustment */
}

.article {
  margin: 5px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  flex: 0 0 100px;   /* adjustment */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="article">article1</div>
    <div class="article">article2</div>
    <div class="article">article3</div>
    <div class="article">article4</div>
    <div class="article">article5</div>
    <div class="article">article6</div>
    <div class="article">article7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">col 2</div>
  <div class="column">col 3</div>
</div>
```