# flex-grow is not working with images

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flex-grow

Currently, I'm trying to make a list. On the left side images which fit into my "display flex layout" and resize on all browsers. My "flex-grow layout" list 1 for the image and 3 for the description. Without images, everything is fine, but with my image (100% width) it does not fit into the 1/3 of the row ...

Does anybody know a solution?

```css
#main {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}
#main div:nth-of-type(1) {-webkit-flex-grow: 1;}
#main div:nth-of-type(2) {-webkit-flex-grow: 3;}
#main div:nth-of-type(1) {flex-grow: 1;}
#main div:nth-of-type(2) {flex-grow: 3;}
#main img { width: 100% }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;"><img src="http://www.der-eyecatcher.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Lampe-silber-Schirm_1.jpg"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">Description</div>
</div>

<hr>flex-grow without Image<hr>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">Description</div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Simon

Comment: Flexgrow is not the same as `width`: Your image expands the div as it should.

Comment: Try just `flex:1`  instead - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bYLreW

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have the image container – the flex item `div` – set to `flex-grow: 1`. That's fine.

Except the default value of `flex-basis` is `auto` ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property)).

So, you're telling the item that it's initial main size (i.e., `flex-basis`) should be the size of its content (the image). That's exactly what's happening. The item takes the natural size of the image.

Add this to your code:

- `flex-basis: 0`

OR, better yet, this:

- `flex: 1`

which is short for:

- `flex: 1 1 0`

which is short for:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

*From the spec:*

> [**7.2. Components of
>   Flexibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components)
>
> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex` shorthand
>   rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the shorthand
>   correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate [common
>   uses](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).

For an explanation of the difference between `flex-basis: auto` and `flex-basis: 0`, see this post:

- [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)

```css
#main {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
}

/* adjustment here */
#main div:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex: 1;
}

#main div:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

#main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;"><img src="http://www.der-eyecatcher.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Lampe-silber-Schirm_1.jpg"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">Description</div>
</div>

<hr>flex-grow without Image
<hr>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">Description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-basis: 0 (actually flexBasis since I'm working on react native) saved me! Thanks for saving me after hours of struggling