# Expand Bootstrap Inline Form to Fit Full-Width of Column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I'm new to Bootstrap and have been messing around with v4. My question is on making an inline form expand to the full-width available inside the column.

Below is my markup:

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-2 title">

            <h2>Make a Gift:</h2>
            <p>Give Generously</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">


            <form class="form-inline ">

                <label class="sr-only">Donation Type</label>
                <select class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2">
                    <option selected>One Time Donation</option>
                    <option value="1">Recurring Donation</option>
                </select>

                <label class="sr-only">Donation Amount</label>
                <input class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2" type="number" placeholder="Donation Amount">

                <label class="sr-only">Choose Fund</label>
                <select class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2">
                    <option selected>Syria Emergency</option>
                    <option value="1">Winterisation</option>
                </select>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-1">Donate Now</button>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I'd love to hear from the community on where to go from here.

Comment: Do you want to make the inline form, vertical or horizontal ?

Comment: what is the issue? your code seems to be working fine https://jsfiddle.net/ppb40n39/

Comment: @Lakindu The form is already inline horizontally but need fields and button to fit full-width of available space in col-lg-10.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Check out the question.

Comment: @Lakindu How do I go by doing so?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex-grow` to utilize the available spaces. In your case you can apply to the form-controls like below.

```
.form-inline .form-control {flex-grow:1}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ppb40n39/2/)

You can get more information for expanding items using flex on the below stack overflow link.

[Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520932/make-flex-grow-expand-items-based-on-their-original-size)

Comment: yes, this is correct and with bootstrap just use class="form-control flex-grow-1"