# How to establish the number of columns in flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 4 elements to be displayed on a mobile screen. I want to have them display in 2 columns of 2 elements each on portrait view and a single row for all 4 of them on landscape view.

Portrait view:

```
Plan 1  Plan 2
Plan 3  Plan 4
```

Landscape view:

```
Plan 1  Plan 2 Plan 3  Plan 4
```

This is my html code:

```
<div class="flex">
 <label>Plan 1</label>
 <label>Plan 2</label>
 <label>Plan 3</label>
 <label>Plan 4</label>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.flex {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

I can pull out only 1 column. What should I do?

Comment: `label` elements should only be used to label form elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of `vmin` and `vmax` here.

To make items wrap to the next line, use `flex-wrap: wrap`.

If the flex container does not take up the full width of the screen, replace these values with `.flex`'s corresponding dimensions

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex label {
  max-width: 50vmin;
  min-width: 25vmax;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
 <label>Plan 1</label>
 <label>Plan 2</label>
 <label>Plan 3</label>
 <label>Plan 4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: My body needs to be set to 100% both height and width. Will it still work like that?

Comment: @CainNuke Yes, vmin and vmax take their values based on the viewport (dimensions of your device/window) instead of the size of the entire page. `50vw` means 50% of your devices width, `50vh` is 50% of height, `50vmin` is 50% of the height or width, whichever is smallest

Comment: Thank you, your answer was the most simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) if you can, as that supports multiple columns natively.

That being said, this is possible with flexbox, it's just a little counter intuitive. Instead of using `flex-direction: column;`, you should leave it in `flex-direction: row;` and set `flex-wrap: wrap;` to enable elements to wrap to new lines. Then, if you set `flex: 0 0 50%;` (meaning don't grow, don't shrink, and use 50% as the basis width), you'll get two columns with additional elements wrapping below.

To change this to stack on portrait view, you can use a media query to change the `flex-basis` to 100% (the third parameter in the `flex` property).

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex label {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
    .flex label {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
 <label>Plan 1</label>
 <label>Plan 2</label>
 <label>Plan 3</label>
 <label>Plan 4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Wanted to note here that `flex-basis` sets the initial minimum size of the flex item (for anyone else who was confused like me): MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width for each column. You can set the width for the children of the `.flex` class or you can create another one. For example, if you want 4 columns you'll have to set `width: 25%` for each `label`. For the different sizes you'll have to use the `@media` to set the sizes, like:

```
/* Phone landscape and bigger */
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .label {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex properties and media queries to make the adjustment between screen orientations / sizes.

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
  flex: 1; /* see Note 1 */
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
h3:first-child {
  display: none;
}

@media ( max-width: 600px ) {
  h3:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
  h3:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
  article {
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* see Note 2 */
  }
  section {
    flex: 1 0 34%; /* see Note 2 */
  }
}

/* can ignore styles below; decorative only */
article { padding: 5px; background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
section { height: 50px; background-color: lightgreen; border: 1px solid #ccc;
display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; font-size: 1.2em; }
```

```html
<h3>Portrait View</h3>
<h3>Landscape View</h3>
<article>
  <section>Plan 1</section>
  <section>Plan 2</section>
  <section>Plan 3</section>
  <section>Plan 4</section>
</article>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myt937fa/)

Notes.

1. `flex: 1` assigns an equal proportion of container space to each item, causing all to be equal width. More details here:  [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)
2. With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the flex shorthand, there's no need for `flex-basis` to be 50%, which can result in one item per row due to the margins. Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap. In this case, with `flex-basis: 34%`, there's plenty of space for the margins, but never enough space for a third item.