# How to get the divs reduced to 1 or 2 column when viewed on a cell phone?

Tags: css

**Question**:  How to get the divs reduced to 1 or 2 column when viewed on a cell phone?

[See codepen](https://codepen.io/davidhelp/pen/eYXeKaN?editors=1100)

At the site you can move the slider / divider to the right to shrink the page.

I would want 1 or 2 columns when viewed on a cell phone.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .wrapper {   /* the rows & columns */
  display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 20% 15% 15%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    max-width: 95%;
  }
}

  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .content {  /* the text at the top */
  display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    min-width: 95%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following examples switch to `display: flex` for the double columns, and `display: block` for the single column.

## Double column

This example shows two columns below 481px.

```css
*    {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 body {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #3b6ea5;  
 }

@media(min-width: 482px){
  .wrapper {  /* the rows & columns */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 20% 15% 15%;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: #427BB8;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 30px;
    justify-content : center;
    border: solid 2px #FF9900;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  }
 }

 .content {  /* the text at the top */
   margin: 0px auto;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   border: solid 2px #ffffff;
   width: 60%;   
 }

 #div1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    justify-content : center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

 #div2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 5;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    justify-content : center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

 .box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

  p {
     font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 100%;
     font-weight: normal;
     line-height: 1.4em;
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     padding-left: 15px;
     padding-right: 15px;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
  }

  h2 {
     font-family: 'Bookman Old Style', serif;
     text-align: center;
     color: #000000;
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     padding-left: 0px;
     padding-right: 0px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
  }

@media(max-width: 481px){
  .wrapper {  /* the rows & columns */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
 }

@media(max-width: 481px){
  .wrapper > * {  /* the rows & columns */
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    width: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .wrapper > *:nth-child(odd) {  /* the rows & columns */
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="content"> <h2>GRID Auto Rows </h2>
 <div class="wrapper">

  <div id="div1"> 1  </div>

  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
  <div class="box i">I</div>
  <div class="box j">J</div>

  <div id="div2"> 2  </div>

  <div class="box k">K</div>
  <div class="box l">L</div>

</div>
</div>
```

## Single Column

This example shows a single column below 481px.

```css
*    {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 body {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #3b6ea5;  
 }

@media(min-width: 482px){
  .wrapper {  /* the rows & columns */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 20% 15% 15%;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: #427BB8;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 30px;
    justify-content : center;
    border: solid 2px #FF9900;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  }
 }

 .content {  /* the text at the top */
   margin: 0px auto;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   border: solid 2px #ffffff;
   width: 60%;   
 }

 #div1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    justify-content : center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

 #div2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 5;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
    justify-content : center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

 .box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

  p {
     font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 100%;
     font-weight: normal;
     line-height: 1.4em;
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     padding-left: 15px;
     padding-right: 15px;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
  }

  h2 {
     font-family: 'Bookman Old Style', serif;
     text-align: center;
     color: #000000;
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     padding-left: 0px;
     padding-right: 0px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
  }

@media(max-width: 481px){
  .wrapper {  /* the rows & columns */
    display: block;
  }
 }

@media(max-width: 481px){
  .wrapper > * {  /* the rows & columns */
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="content"> <h2>GRID Auto Rows </h2>
 <div class="wrapper">

  <div id="div1"> 1  </div>

  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
  <div class="box i">I</div>
  <div class="box j">J</div>

  <div id="div2"> 2  </div>

  <div class="box k">K</div>
  <div class="box l">L</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I would not have known to use display: flex or display: block


I redid some of the code and found some of the solution here as well:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929432/how-to-establish-the-number-of-columns-in-flex


BTW if you add as example a width: 45%; you will get 2 columns. If larger then you have single rows.

Comment: @David Yeah I think I was using display: flex earlier which default behaviour will want to squish everything in the same row, unless you use flex-wrap: wrap;. There's a few ways to do this, just depends what your project allows you to use. Sometimes peoples question have more complex conditions that aren't mentioned. Glad it worked for you! Feel free to accept my answer.