# Why is overflow-y: hidden creating a horizontal scroll bar in my flex layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two panels side by side. The right-hand one contains species names, which should not wrap (they're small enough to occupy only a small part of the screen). The left-hand panel contains more things, and occupy most of the screen. Here's my code.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#left {
  background-color: skyblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}
#right {
  background-color: indianRed;
 white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id='left'>
Some text wide enough to compete with the red panel -- some more words needed.
</div>
<div id='right'>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
</div>
```

When there's no scrollbar, the width of the right-hand panel is correct. But as soon as I add a vertical scrollbar (`overflow-y: auto`), it's width gets much smaller, creating also a horizontal scrollbar. Why? And how to solve it? I only want the vertical scrollbar. The width of the panel should be enough to contain all the words on it.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#left {
  background-color: skyblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}
#right {
  background-color: indianRed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='left'>
Some text wide enough to compete with the red panel -- some more words needed.
</div>
<div id='right'>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you try overflow-x:hidden?

Comment: you can try `overflow-x:hidden`?

Comment: @Sfili_81 That's causing part of the text to disappear.

Comment: something like this? [https://jsfiddle.net/cL815woq/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/cL815woq/2/)

Comment: @Sfili_81 That's breaking the text, which I don't want.

Comment: just leave `overflow: auto` instead of setting `overflow-y`

Comment: @AkashShrivastava That's creating an undesired horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @Rodrigo what text is breaking in the fiddle?

Comment: @Sfili_81 "Some names a little larger" is becoming "Some names/a little larger"

Comment: Add `flex-basis:0;` to `div#left`

Comment: @ZohirSalak You're a genius!! It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ZohirSalak Please add that as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @Rodrigo posted more detailed answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current flex properties are as follows:

**div#left**

```
flex-grow:1;
flex-shrink:1;
flex-basis:auto;
```

This means:

The div's width will be content first `flex-basis:auto;` then fill the remaining space `flex-grow:1;`

**div#right**

```
flex-grow:0;
flex-shrink:1;
flex-basis:auto;
```

This means:

The div's  width will be content first `flex-basis:auto;` And shrink to fit `flex-shrink:1;`

This is why you see horizontal scrollbar when the vertical scroll is added, because it eats from the overall width.

---

## Solution #1

`flex-basis:0;` on the left div which will make it fill the remaining space first then lay down the content

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#left {
  background-color: skyblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

#right {
  background-color: indianRed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='left'>
  Some text wide enough to compete with the red panel -- some more words needed.
</div>
<div id='right'>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
</div>
```

---

## Solution #2

`flex-shrink:0;` on the right div which will prevent it from shrinking

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#left {
  background-color: skyblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}

#right {
  background-color: indianRed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1em;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='left'>
  Some text wide enough to compete with the red panel -- some more words needed.
</div>
<div id='right'>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
</div>
```

Issue with this solution is that if the content in the left div is too long there will be overflow

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  /* removed to illustrate the problem */
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
}
#left {
  background-color: skyblue;
  flex-grow: 1; 
  padding: 1em;
}
#right {
  background-color: indianRed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  /* if you remove this there will be no overflow because the right div will shrink to fit*/
  flex-shrink:0; 
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#left>div{
    /* I eyeballed this value to fit the snippet in SO*/
    width:500px; 
    background-color:Red;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
  <p>Some names.</p>
  <p>Some names a little larger.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great solution and explanation. Hit the nail on the head. For anybody wanting more details see [the difference between `flex-basis: auto` and `flex-basis: 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276).

Answer (score 2):

Its because of long text inside your `div` and you set `white-space: nowrap;` which prevent it to overflow

Use

```
#right {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: The text is not so long. If I can have `nowrap` without the vertical scrollbar, why not with it?

Comment: Dear static width of that container prevent it to adjust its size according to the viewport so you need to overflow that text. You can also use media quries for that.

Answer (score -1):

Define both scrollbars.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* not auto */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It was browser's default functionality. If you add any of one attribute value `auto` then default it will add both scrollbars.

If you want to add specific then you must need to add in your code.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: This hides part of the text inside the right panel.

Comment: Add another style attribute `word-break: break-word;`.

Comment: I don't want to break the lines!

Comment: There are only **three ways** to handle your problem. You must need to **break line or hide over-flow text** and the third one is make **scroll visible**.

Comment: There's a fourth option: to measure every line of text, and then define the width of the right panel accordingly, which is ridiculous, because the CSS is there to do exactly that!

Comment: That's why I told you there is three 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204018/discussion-between-mayur-jotaniya-and-rodrigo).

Answer (score -1):

If set `overflow-y` explicitly you might need to set `overflow-x` as well.

Or you can set `width` value or right div.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
#left {
  background-color: skyblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}
#right {
  background-color: indianRed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='left'>
Some text wide enough to compete with the red panel -- some more words needed.
</div>
<div id='right'>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
<p>Some names.</p>
<p>Some names a little larger.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want any horizontal scrollbar. As I said, the species names (on the right) are small, and fit perfectly on the screen (I'm not considering smartphones).

Comment: oh, missed there, updated snippet, setting the width might get you what you want.