# Scroll an element that's deeply below an ancestor that knows its height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have something like the following:

```css
#page {
  height: 200px; /* just for illustration, would be 100vh */
  border: 1px solid black; /* just for illustration */
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#nav {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  
  flex: none;
}

#content {
  background-color: lightGreen;
  display: flex;
  
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.problem {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="nav">
    I'm a nav bar!
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <section>
      Stuff
    </section>
    <section>
      More stuff
      <div class="problem">
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the page to never scroll, and I only want the large red rectangle to scroll within the `<section>`. What rules do I need to add so that the red rectangle understands its parent's bounds?

Comment: `min-height: 0;` to #content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your section a flexbox container and then set [the flex CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
(short for [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink), and [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis))

You want it to spread or shrink to occupy to all the remaining height => `flex-grow: 1;` and `flex-shrink: 1;`

Explanation for the flex-basis (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520932/make-flex-grow-expand-items-based-on-their-original-size#answer-43529572)):

> The flex-basis factor
>
> When flex-basis is 0, flex-grow ignores the size of the content in
>   flex items and treats all space on the line as free space.
>
> This is absolute sizing. All space on the line is distributed.

It's what we need here => `flex-basis: 0;`

---

Here what's the code will look like:

```
section {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex; /* added */
  flex-direction:column; /* added */
}

.problem {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 0; /* added */
}
```

```css
#page {
  height: 100vh; /* just for illustration, would be 100vh */
  border: 1px solid black; /* just for illustration */
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#nav {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  
  flex: none;
}

#content {
  background-color: lightGreen;
  display: flex;
  
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.problem {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="nav">
    I'm a nav bar!
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <section>
      Stuff
    </section>
    <section>
      More stuff
      <div class="problem">
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you add more content in your `div.problem`, it will have the expected behavior

```css
#page {
  height: 100vh; /* just for illustration, would be 100vh */
  border: 1px solid black; /* just for illustration */
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#nav {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  
  flex: none;
}

#content {
  background-color: lightGreen;
  display: flex;
  
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.problem {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="nav">
    I'm a nav bar!
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <section>
      Stuff
    </section>
    <section>
      More stuff
      <div class="problem">
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically         
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically         
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
        Oh no I'm huge and should scroll vertically
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
#page {
  height: 200px; /* just for illustration, would be 100vh */
  border: 1px solid black; /* just for illustration */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#nav {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#content {
  background-color: lightGreen;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.problem {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
}
```