# How to set equal width for flex elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

Why blocks `.b` have different width? How to set it equal?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent>div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.parent .b {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Why blocks `<div class="cell">` have different width?

Comment: You didn't close the parent div.

Comment: Problem is in another

Comment: [`flex-basis: auto` vs  `flex-basis: 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43529572/3597276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: use CSS grid and auto-fit:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.parent>div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By I have different number .cell in parent, how to be? i

Comment: Could you share how to use calc in my case?

Comment: So, directly in CSS? `.cell {flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 4);}` How to get  total number 4? Using what?

Comment: Bu how to pass from JS to CSS total number??

Answer (score 1):

Second re-edit**

First choice you can do is just set a flex on the parent element as this will only effect the first element below that, which in this case is the `cell` class, i will add a border on the cell class so you can see this in effect

```
  <div class="parent">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="b"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="b"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="b"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="b"></div>
      </div>
  <div>
```

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
}

.cell {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

here you can set the size of your parent width which will be the size across your screen, you can then set the width of the .cell childs and they will all then be the same, but only at a maximum of the parent

** second option you can do

Here is a simpler version, and i have added 3 different classes to show how you can choose the sizing you want

```
<div class="parent">
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="c"></div>
<div>
```

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
}

.a {
  flex: 40%;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}
.b {
  flex: 20%;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.c {
  flex: 20%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Of course you can change them back and have them all be called the same class, and just assign one width and again they will all be the same... i hope this helps

Comment: Parent can contain different number of `.cell`

Comment: I have more that 4 cells

Comment: you can still use the flex: and then percentage and it will size all of them the same size

Comment: Could you share how to make it?

Comment: sure give me 1 minute and i will re-edit my answer with two different options for you

Comment: re-edited, this should help you a bit better understand now

Answer (score 0):

I think they all are in same width. You need to use this css instead of the `.parent>div` selector

```
.cell {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.parent .b {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.b {
  height: 50px;
}
.cell:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}
.cell:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
.cell:nth-child(4) {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="b">hi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="b">hi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="b">hi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="b">hi</div>
  </div>
<div>
```