# Text in flex box item is causing flex box item to expand

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a flex box container and 3 child `div`s in it and 
I want to keep the sizes of the 3 in same the same ratio (1:1:1)
but when I add some text into the child `div`s, they change ratio to cover up for the text overflow
**Like this:**

```css
#container
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:  center;
}
.item
{
    color: white;
  flex-grow:1;

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
before text:
<div id="container"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-color:red;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:green;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
<br>
after text:
<div id="container"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-color:red;">hello there</div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:green;">hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:blue;">no</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so how do I maintain the aspect ratio while adding text? 
**NOTE:** 
hiding the overflow is acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `flex-grow:1` to `flex:1`

```css
#container
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:  center;
}
.item
{
    color: white;
  flex:1;
 min-width:0; /* thanks to Temani */
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
before text:
<div id="container"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-color:red;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:green;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
<br>
after text:
<div id="container"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-color:red;">hello there</div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:green;">hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:blue;">no</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: + min-width:0 (or overflow:auto) to make the middle one shrink on small screens

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add `flew-basis: 0` to `.item`. See updated example below:

```css
#container
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:  center;
}
.item
{
    color: white;
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis: 0;

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
before text:
<div id="container"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-color:red;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:green;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
<br>
after text:
<div id="container"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-color:red;">hello there</div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:green;">hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:blue;">no</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. I have been to fast. Have not seen that the answer has just been given. Additional @gowthamRajJ presented an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is caused by the default value `flex-basis: auto` for `.item`. You might want to consider adding `flex-basis: 33.33%`(100/no of columns) and also a `max-width` of same value.

In your case `flex-basis: 0` would also work. Check: [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520932/make-flex-grow-expand-items-based-on-their-original-size)

Answer (score -1):

Simply, change `flex-grow: 1;` to `flex: 1` or to `width: 33.3333%` to `.item`

```css
#container
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:  center;
}
.item
{
    color: white;
    width: 33.3333%;

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
before text:
<div id="container"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-color:red;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:green;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
<br>
after text:
<div id="container"> 
 <div class="item" style="background-color:red;">hello there</div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:green;">hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
 <div class="item" style="background-color:blue;">no</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```