# flex vs flex-grow producing different results

Tags: css, flexbox

Learning Flexbox & I don't understand why flex property is behaving the way it is.  As I understand it, flex is simply shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis with the last two being optional.

In my example below, I expected the same result using flex-grow vs flex with just the first value defined.  I am getting different results but I don't understand why. The results in the first container is what I was expecting in both. Seems so straight forward I don't know what I am missing - shorthand properties don't work the way I am understanding them?  Appreciate any help.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.item1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.item2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.item3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0;
}

.item4 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item item1"></div>
    <div class="item item2"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="item item3"></div>
    <div class="item item4"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set only `flex-grow`, the `flex-basis` property remains unaffected. It still defaults to `flex-basis: auto`.

When you use the `flex` property, `flex-basis` gets reset to 0.

So `flex: 0` is shorthand for `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-basis: 0`. This means 0 width.

With `flex-grow: 0` you still have `flex-basis: auto`.

To understand the difference between `flex-basis: 0` and `flex-basis: auto`, see this post:

- [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)

Comment: I understand now; thank you for the explanation and link to post on flex-basis.  That was a helpful piece I had missed in tutorials.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using flex instead of the trio grow shrink and basis is little bit trickier than how it looks..
the second and third parameters are not optional , you can choose to use flex alone with one value two or 3 but it will behave differently depending on the value you pass

according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) : case of a unitless number as flex value

```css
flex : <number>  ;
/*translates to :*/ 
flex : <number> 1 0 ;
```

in your case flex is set to 0 so you have :

```css
flex : 0  ;
/*translates to :*/ 
flex : 0 1 0 ;
```

so flex-basis which is the last one is set to 0 and flex grow is 0 so its not the same as **item1** . having no basis and shrink set to 1 , item 4 will take the whole row since he has grow of 1

for item 4 you have

```css
flex : 1  ;
/*translates to :*/ 
flex : 1 1 0 ;
```

Comment: Thanks; that was helpful.